# Batch - Get value of command not working

Tags: batch-file, windows-phone-8, window, command

I use the below command in batch file to list the directory structure in windowsphone

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool"\ISETool.exe dir:\output deviceindex:2 27dsfs49618f-5f26-4a15-808c-a55af2cc7b94

The above command works fine and lists the directory. I am trying to get the value of the above command in a variable 'theValue'  like this

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool"\ISETool.exe dir:\Adobe\CameraRaw deviceindex:2 27dsfs49618f-5f26-4a15-808c-a55af2cc7b94') do @set theValue=%%a

This is giving me error. Can any body tell how to get the value of above command in a variable. The spaces in the command are seem to be causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try utilising redirection:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool\ISETool.exe" dir:\output deviceindex:2 27dsfs49618f-5f26-4a15-808c-a55af2cc7b94 > output.temp

set /p theValue=<output.tmp
del output.tmp
```

And that should do what you want. To use the `for` command try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool\ISETool.exe" dir:\Adobe\CameraRaw deviceindex:2 27dsfs49618f-5f26-4a15-808c-a55af2cc7b94') do (
set theValue=%%a
)
```

You only had one quotation mark.

Hope this helped, Mona.